# Nginx rewrite, reset rewrite or add extensions to a specific directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Here's my nginx site config:

```
server {
server_name DOMAIN.COM;
access_log /srv/www/DOMAIN.COM/logs/access.log;
error_log /srv/www/DOMAIN.COM/logs/error.log;
root /srv/www/DOMAIN.COM/public_html;

location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {  return 302 /$1$is_args$args;  }
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

}
```

How would I make it so "domain.com/directory/" will NOT rewrite any URLs and keep the file extensions? For example make it so that "domain.com/directory/filename" and all other files in the directory rewrite to "domain.com/directory/filename.php" but in every other directory remove ".php".

Comment: The [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133287/access-index-html-in-folder-without-301-redirect/35188146#35188146) might help as a guide.

Comment: @RichardSmith sorry, I'm a noob to nginx. I just switched from Apache. I tried a few things using your answer as a guide but I just can't get it right. Could you push me in the right direction?

Comment: Edit your question and be more specific about what you are trying to achieve with examples.

Comment: @RichardSmith done.

Comment: It seems to me that it does that already. What are you observing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposed solution (showing only the location blocks):

```
location ~ ./$ { rewrite ^(.*)/ $1 last; }

location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)\.(php|htm)) { return 302 $1$is_args$args; }

    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm @php;
}

location @php {
    try_files $uri.php $uri/index.php =404;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location /somedirectory {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 break;

    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm @php;
}
```

The `location ~ /$` block silently removes any trailing slash as this interferes with the `try_files` directives later.

Notice that the `location ~ \.php$` block has been removed so that `.php` URIs are now processed by the `location /` block.

The `location /` block will redirect URIs with an `.html` and `.php` extension (which is consistent with the two `if` blocks from your original configuration.

The `location /` block tries several URIs including the list from the `index` directive (except `index.php` which is handled later).

Notice that the `$uri/` element and the `index` directive are no longer used.

The final action is to invoke the named `location @php` block to handle `.php` and `index.php` files.

Up to this point, the functionality is similar to your existing configuration.

The `location /somedirectory` modifies the behaviour for URIs below `somedirectory`. It allows `.php` URIs to keep their extension by silently removing it prior to the `try_files` directive.

Comment: Hm... This solution does not seem to work. It adds ".php" to every filename.

Comment: ah, my apologies, I should have been more specific. What would I have to do to only add .php to files in a specific directory but remove .PHP in all other directories? But either way it still adds .php to every page I access.

Comment: Thank you so much for assisting me on configuring nginx. You helped a lot! Everything works fine now. :)

Comment: Yeah, everything works fine except that when someone adds .php?arg to the end of a PHP file, nginx will serve it as a download.

Comment: @MiguelRenaud-Nolte I have updated the answer to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, works now except when I access my domain it says "500 Internal Server Error", but when I add /index to the domain it works. Any ideas?

Comment: @MiguelRenaud-Nolte I added a `.` to the first regex